# Finding Lon Values that are close together on uneven lists

Tags: matlab, for-loop, if-statement, latitude-longitude

I have two matrices of Longitude values. I would like to identify points that are close together within the two lists. My problem is the lists are of different lengths

One of them is named Lon_pair and the other is named Lon_epa.

Lon_pair is of size

```
size(Lon_pair) 
12635       1
```

Lon_epa is of size

```
size(Lon_epa)
20560       1
```

How do I find points within Lon_pair that are close to those within Lon_epa? Or find the difference between them?

Edit: Adding Code

```
clear all
close all

filename_pair = 'C:\Users\tadams15\Desktop\ALL_PAIR.csv';
data = xlsread(filename_pair);

Lon_pair = data(:,2);
Lat_pair = data(:,3);
Label_pair = data(:,4);

filename_epa = 'C:\Users\tadams15\Desktop\aqs.csv'
data2 = xlsread(filename_epa);
Lon_epa = data2(:,4);
Lat_epa = data2(:,5);

%% Find Lat/Lon Combos
for j = 1:20560
for i = 2:12636
        d_lon(j) = Lon_epa(:) - Lon_pair(i);
        d_lon_m(j) = d_lon/(9e-06);
        if d_lon(:) < 300
           [row,col] = find(d_lon)
        end
end
end
```

Comment: But what's a difference about the length? You anyway have to iterate through all two lists. You don't compare like List1(1) to List2(1), List1(2) to List2(2).

Comment: I believe this problem was defined incorrectly or did not provide sufficient detail for the characteristics of lists. You may use a `for` loop and cite the longer one. You may also want to provide more detail for what you meant by "close together".

Comment: @Y.Chang Hello! Sorry, I'm fairly new to this. I have a two list of longitude points. The lists are the lengths specified. I'm converting their values to meters and then I would like to find the index of each longitude that is less than 500 meters away from another longitude value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't the most efficient for very large datasets, but it may work for you (or least be a starting point). Below double-loops through both datasets, finds distances between points, keeps the minimum and row number of companion dataset corresponding to minimum distance.

```
% set up dummy data to mimic UTM x,y (northing,easting) coordinates
x1 = randi([0,50000],20,1);
y1 = randi([-230000,420000],20,1);

x2 = randi([0,50000],12,1);
y2 = randi([-230000,420000],12,1);
% end set up


mydist = NaN(length(x1), 2); % pre-allocate

for ii = 1:length(mydist)
    xa = x1(ii);
    ya = y1(ii);
    temp_dist = NaN(length(x2), 2);
    for jj = 1:length(x2)
        xb = x2(jj);
        yb = y2(jj);
        temp_dist(jj, 1) = sqrt((xa-xb)^2 + (ya-yb)^2); % if you have the Statistics Toolbox, you can just use pdist
        temp_dist(jj, 2) = jj; % this is the row number in set2
    [value, index] = min(temp_dist(:,1));
    mydist(ii, 1) = value;
    mydist(ii, 2) = temp_dist(index, 2);
    end
end

mydist_table = array2table(mydist);
mydist_table.Properties.VariableNames = {'Clostest_Distance', 'Set2_RowNumber'};
```